# Reset value of jsf InputSecret

Tags: jsf-2

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" name="password" value="#{dummyMB.passowrd}" >
    <f:validator validatorId="CustomValidator"/>
    <f:attribute name="passwordValue" value="#{dummyMB.password}"/>
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="ErrorMessage"/>
    <f:validateRequired/>
</h:inputSecret>
```

When there is a validation error, the password field is cleared, because of default value of attribute redisplay="false", but it does not clear the previously entered password from the backing bean property.How can i reset this backing bean property on event of validation error.

Answer (score 1):

The best call here would be create a method resetValues () in the backing bean, reset the values of the input fields in this method and call this on validation problem. Please have a look at the link

http://www.jakobk.com/2010/06/validation-errors-and-bean-updates/

Comment: Thanks @techboost, as i was using Richfaces, i explored more into it, so implement it as per your post and came up with a solution. i used the below code: <rich:validator event="blur" oninvalid="#{dummyMB.resetPassword()}"/> and reverted back to redisplay="false" . It solved my problem.